# Mobile app container css position not working [Tailwind CSS] [React]

Tags: reactjs, mobile, tailwind-css

I'm creating a football app and I'm placing a div on top of another to select the player position but when I scroll down there's a gap between the div on top stays at the same place but I want it to be "fixed" even when scrolling.

This is the div that I want to be fixed and on top of all.

[image]

```
<div
      className={`absolute top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen w-screen rounded bg-white text-black transition-transform duration-200 ease-in-out ${transitionClass}`}
    >
      <div className="flex h-[10%] w-full justify-between p-4">
        <div className="w-16"></div>
        <div className="text-2xl font-semibold">
          <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="flex w-16 justify-end">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark} onClick={onClose} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex w-full flex-col px-4">{children}</div>
    </div>
```

This is the div that is supposed to be under the other one

```
<div
      className={`absolute top-0 left-0 z-40 min-h-[100vh] w-screen rounded bg-white text-black transition-transform duration-200 ease-in-out ${transitionClass} `}
    >
      <div className="flex h-[10%] w-full justify-between p-4">
        <div className="w-16"></div>
        <div className="text-2xl font-semibold">
          <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="flex w-16 justify-end">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark} onClick={onClose} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex w-full flex-col px-4">{children}</div>
    </div>
```

This is the behavior

[image]

I've tried to change several times the position of the elements but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Second time, I found the answer straight away after I posted hahaha...

It seems since i was using some transform classes to make an animation it was breaking the normal behavior of the position fixed

```
const [transitionClass, setTransitionClass] = useState("translate-y-full");

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (editMode) return setTransitionClass("translate-y-0");
      setTransitionClass("translate-y-full");
    }, 100);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [editMode]);
```

I just removed the "translate-y-0" to "" and it started working.